# Firebase authentication in AMP

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to use amp-access for [firebase authentication](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web)?
Is there a way to integrate Firebase for the subscriber login/signup in AMP page?
If amp-access cannot be used, what are the recommended alternatives? 
Eg. redirect users to the non-AMP page when they subscribe to see locked content?

Answer (score 0):

There's no authorization protocol of any kind available by default in Firebase. If it's just authentication, a publisher can simply use Firebase services to simplify building their login page, which will then be configured for amp-access. They would also need to add authorization endpoint that yields whether the document can be fully accessed.
See https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-access/amp-access.md

Answer (score 0):

No, Firebase services require their javascript libraries, and AMP does not allow that. Endpoints in js work, but Firebase scripts are considered external. Now the AMP team could simply whitelist Firebase scripts and be done with it, but...

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific AMP Firebase component but this example shows a general way for creating authentication with AMP https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/login_requiring/login

**EDIT:**
I created an example of simple login/logout https://github.com/matjazonline/amp-firebase-login