# Can I send and receive data from AMP Emails using Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, amp-html, amp-email

Is there any way to integrate Firebase functions or API inside AMP email so that I can list data from Firebase database and also submit data from amp form to Firebase database.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459364/firebase-authentication-in-amp), it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done.

**1. Submitting data from AMP Email to Firebase.**

For submitting data, you need to use [AMP Form](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/?format=email). All that is required is an endpoint with ssl enabled which can accept post data.

```
<form method="post"
    action-xhr="https://your-firebase-url.com/post"    target="_top">
```

In firebase, you can achieve this using functions. You can see some examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995433/how-firebase-cloud-functions-handle-http-post-method).

**2. List data from firebase.**
Listing of data from third-party url can be done in amp using [this](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/interactivity/remote-data/?format=email). Data from firebase can be made available by get api accessible via REST endpoint exposed from function again. As in steps 1.

From documentation:

> `<amp-state>` supports fetching remote data via its srcattribute, which
> fetches JSON from a CORS endpoint. This fetch is performed once and at
> page load and is useful for ensuring freshness of data (especially
> when served from a cache).
>
> You can also bind the src attribute for the  element. This
> means that a user action can trigger a fetch of remote JSON data into
> the page's bindable state.

AMP just need an enpoint. It however can't load Firebase SDK and use non-rest approach. As AMP doesn't permit use of other js libraries.